# How to handle File in use Exception?

Tags: c#, .net, file-io, exception

I'm writting a C# winform app that is writting document on the local drive. The document read value from the form and write them on the document after each button click. After the button is clicked and the document is written, the document is shown using `Process.Start`

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(pathToTheDocument));
```

My question is how do I handle the File in use Exception. Should I try to kill the process using the file (if it's possible)? should I MessageBox a warning? I can also create another document on the drive.

What is the best way to handle those kind of exception?

Comment: Yes you should handle most (all) `IOException` but it is completely up to you what to do when you get such exception... Except obviously trying to kill process that uses the file (non-polite and often impossible under user's account).

Comment: What would your users want you to do?

Comment: Who is lockign the file?  You (via another process or app) ... or something else (Like Microsoft Word).     If I had a doc open in Word, and you killed the process, I'd be irked.

Comment: The document in question is a pdf. It's read-only. I agree that killing the process isn't a good solution but I'm just looking if someone has a good solution.

Answer (score 3):

I dont think there is "one solution to rule them all". I agree with what was commented by @Geoff, eventually you write software for end users to use, and not for your own sake of spilling code. It definitely depends on what your user wants. I would simply ask them what the desired outcome is as part of the RR (Requirements Review).

If so happeneds that there isn't a user to ask, i think a friendly "This file is being used" notification would suffice. I would definitely **NOT** attempt to kill any other process currently occupying the desired file.